# Coverity support issue for Borland C++Builder

Tags: c++builder, coverity

When I compile my code using Borland C++Builder (it is necessary for me to use only the Borland compiler), bcc32.exe is able to compile the code successfully. When I build this same code with the `cov-build` command inside of cmd.exe, the build fails with errors like:

> cannot open source file "iostream"

What is the possible reason behind this, and how do I debug it?

Here is the code

[image]

Comment: Where on disk is the file ? Does it end in .h or not ? How are your includes set up ?

Comment: The .cpp is the file extension .You can have a look on to the code through attached image . The Test code is in separate folder . I am going inside the folder through cmd and compiling the code through bcc32 there only inside the folder of Test code  ; the code is successfully compiled while compiling through native compiler bcc32 . But the compilation fails when I compile the code using cov-build --dir Test cmd /c bcc32 Test.cpp . The build-log says thats ; it is not able to open the file iostream .

Comment: Iostream(.h/.hpp) is the file I am talking about

Comment: @Marged iostream.h

Comment: In which directory ? How are your include paths set up ?

Comment: @Marged "C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\CBuilder6\Include"

Comment: Would you mind not answering questions one by one but all at the same time ?

Comment: @Marged My include path is set up in the bcc32.cfg file like this ::
-I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\CBuilder6\Include" 
-L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\CBuilder6\lib"

Answer (score 0):

Coverity requires that you configure your compiler in the same environment that you build it in. If you fail to do so, the configuration probes will not pick up your include paths, amongst other things.

Comment: Same environment means same PATH, env vars, etc. As in, you can execute your compiler and have it succeed.